# Refactor functions to object methods

Tags: javascript, regex, netbeans, refactoring

After learning about [Object Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp) I wanted to change some of my old code a bit and turn my functions that have this syntax:

```
function name(parameters) {
   code to be executed
}
```

to functions inside variables that look like that:

```
name : function(parameters) { code to be executed }
```

Is there a way to do this automatically? - I was thinking of some RegEx usage in my IDE's replace function but I'm not sure if that's possible.
I'm using NetBeans 8.0.

The ideal solution for me:

I select some code like this:

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

function subtract(x, y) {
    return x - y;
}
```

Execute **1 Button/Shortcut** and the selected code changes to this:

```
add: function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
},
subtract: function(x, y) {
    return x - y;
},
```

The variable I would have to put around those methods then is not a problem, since there aren't that many I want to create. But I have over a 100 functions that I don't want to change manually.

Does anyone know a solution or at least another way that could help me solve this much quicker than changing something in each function over a hundred times?

Comment: `function add` and `function subtract` are anyhow equivalent to `[window]{add:function(){}, subtract:function(){}}`

Comment: I don't understand the point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this (one by one, don't make a replaceAll to see what happens):

```
find: \bfunction\s+(\w+)\s*\(
replace: \1: function (
```

or with $1 in place of \1

Comment: yes, with $1 it worked, and then I just added a `,` at the beginning of the replace expression and I got exactly what I was looking for - big thanks, RegEx master :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex to find :

```
/\bfunction\s([\w\W]+)\(/s
```

And replace :

```
$1 : function (
```